# connect mssql using php on Centos

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I have installed freetds and I want to connect to mssql server via php. I am using centos.

```
root@server [~/php]# tsql -C
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: no
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 5.0
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: no
```

The php code I use to connect to mssql server. (Its located in a subdirectory) I am able to connect to remote mssql server via local mssql server 2008.

```
<?php
// Older FreeTDS installations need the FREETDSCONF Environment variable
putenv('FREETDSCONF=../usr/local/etc/freetds.conf');
// Current release of FreeTDS uses the FREETDS environment variable. So we set both to be sure
putenv('FREETDS=../usr/local/etc/freetds.conf');
$mssql = mssql_connect('116.214.26.236' , 'dbname', 'password');
//mssql_select_db('myDb',$mssql);


if (!$mssql) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}else echo 'Success';

?>
```

My TDS config file

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
# name is found in the installation directory.  
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2

    # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
    # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
    dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

    # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

    # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
    # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
    # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
    text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
    host = symachine.domain.com
    port = 5000
    tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
    host = 116.214.26.236
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

The error that I get

Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: 116.214.26.236 in /home/butter/public_html/investonline/mssql.php on line 6
Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL

Please guide me on where am I getting wrong.

I have searched on google some blogs says the below line value has to be yes,
MS db-lib source compatibility: no

My php.ini conf file

```
mssql
MSSQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Library version FreeTDS

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mssql.allow_persistent  On  On
mssql.batchsize 0   0
mssql.charset   no value    no value
mssql.compatability_mode    Off Off
mssql.connect_timeout   5   5
mssql.datetimeconvert   On  On
mssql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.max_procs Unlimited   Unlimited
mssql.min_error_severity    10  10
mssql.min_message_severity  10  10
mssql.secure_connection On  On
mssql.textlimit Server default  Server default
mssql.textsize  Server default  Server default
mssql.timeout   60  60
```

Also let me know how should I get the logs captured so that I can know at what step there is an error.

Also why am I not able to connect to mssql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO php library to connect with sql server, you can use like this
$output = new PDO ('mssql:host=SERVERHOST;dbname=DBNAME','DBUSERNAME','DBPASSWORD');

Comment: $dsn = 'mssql:host=116.214.26.236;dbname=dbname';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: You will have to enable PDO library then only you can able to connect. You can do it from your php.ini file.

Comment: which line should i uncomment?

Comment: php_pdo_mssql.dll should be uncommented. If you don't have this dll into then you will have to download and put into ext directory.

Comment: downloaded and added file to ext dir added the line extension = "php_pdo_mssql.dll" to php ini in user/lib/ dir it still says Connection failed: could not find driver

Comment: After that, did you check it has been installed correctly? To check it has been installed or not use phpinfo() function. You can see following details 

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers  mssql, mysql, odbc, sqlite2

pdo_mssql
PDO Driver for MSSQL DB-lib enabled
Flavour  MSSQL_70 

If you can not seen this details then you have not installed it sucessfully.

Answer (score -1):

Got to this link and do as it says.  Best to just use Microsoft's driver.

http://strangenut.com/blogs/dacrowlah/archive/2012/04/13/installing-and-using-the-microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver-for-linux.aspx